# Animação mover-se do sentido direito para a esquerda

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esta pequena animação em javascript, que faz o meu background mover-se contudo, isto tem vezes que se move da direita para a esquerda e tem outras vezes que se move da esquerda para a direita.

Como faria para mover-se sempre da direita para a esquerda.

Código:

```
        $('#cores').animate({
 'background-position-x': cd.position
},{ duration: 6000, 'easing':'easeOutCubic'
```

Obrigado.

Comment: O que é o `cd.position`?

Comment: O cd.position é uma parte que recebe via socket do nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Tente definir dois lados, esquerda e direita como variável.
Depois procure fazer com que o background siga esta variável conforme a velocidade e efeito que você queira..

Se for o que eu entendi, você pode seguir esta lógica

Dê uma olhada neste site: [All Animation](http://all-animation.github.io/) , acho que lá deve ter o efeito que você quer! acho que dá pra ter uma boa noção.

Boa sorte!